# Targeting/Scrolling to a React Component that is not a close parent/child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-ref

I have a situation where I want to scroll to a React component from another component that is **not** in a direct or close parent/child relationship.

The structure can be explained as follows:

```
Component A > a parent > a parent > a parent > a parent > a parent > a parent > a child > a child > Component B
```

As you can see it is not direct at all. If the relationship were direct, or even a grandparent/grandchild, I would usually pass a ref. However in this instance, I would need to pass the ref through 10 or so files in order to have access to it, which seems ridiculous.

I know I can use `document.getElementById` (or similar) but was wondering if there is a way I can do this via a ref or something similar in React?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Put the Context Provider in Component A, and Context Consumer in Component B. B the can pass its ref to A via the Context, or vice versa